No continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ (elementary argument)
I want to prove formally that there does not exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$. I get the intuition as to why it is true, since in order to make the logarithm well-defined, you would need to cut off some line from the origin, and create a "gap". I also know how to prove the weaker statement that there is no holomorphic function $f$ that satisfies these constraints.
I tried to look on here, but many prove the holomorphic case or resort to "coverings", which is not something I would learn in an introductory complex analysis class. Is there a purely "elementary" (in the sense that someone who knows real analysis without measures and introductory complex analysis can understand) proof of this fact?

Suppose such an $f$ exists and is continuous. Define $g: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(\theta) = \mathrm{Im}(f(e^{i\theta}))$. It follows $g$ is continuous (since $f$ is) and that $g(0) = g(2\pi)$.
However, by the Intermediate Value Theorem there must exist distinct $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in (0,2\pi)$ with $g(\theta_1) = g(\theta_2)$. This in turn implies $\mathrm{Im}(f(e^{i\theta_1})) =\mathrm{Im}(f(e^{i\theta_2}))$. Since $$\theta_1 = \arg(e^{i\theta_1}) = \arg(e^{f(e^{i\theta_1})}) = \mathrm{Im}(f(e^{i\theta_1}))$$
it follows similarly $\theta_2 = \mathrm{Im}(f(e^{i\theta_2}))$, implying $\theta_1=\theta_2$, giving a contradiction.

How do you know $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are distinct from the IVT? Can you elaborate on that?

Also, you say $i\theta_1=f(e^{i\theta_1})$, but shouldn't it be $i\theta_1=e^{f(i\theta_1)}$?

@AR Sure, either $g$ is constant or there exists some $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ with $g(\theta) \ne g(0),g(2\pi)$. Then there is some $\theta_1 \in (0,\theta)$ and $\theta_2 \in (\theta,2\pi)$ with $g(\theta_1) = \frac{g(\theta)+g(0)}{2} = g(\theta_2)$ by the IVT.
As to your second question, I am not saying $i\theta_1 = f(e^{i\theta_1})$. In the second equality I use the given property of $f$ with $z = e^{i\theta_1}$.

Perfect. Great solution.

If such a function existed, then for all real $\theta$
$$e^{f(\exp(i\theta))}=e^{i\theta}$$
and therefore there would exist an integer-valued function $z(\theta)$ such that
$$f(\exp(i\theta))=i\theta+2\pi i z(\theta)$$
From the continuity of $f$ it follows that $z$ is constant. But then $f(\exp(0))\neq f(\exp(2\pi i)),$ a contradiction.
